# Many2one field one item can select only once in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have 2 fields and many2one field . both field are many2one field for  one method . if i have 2 items in many2one field like 'yes' or 'no'. in first field i will select 'yes' and at the time of second field selection it should get only one item or option i.e 'no'

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

suppose your Many2one field is of com_model 'res.partner'

```
<field name="field1" />
<field name="field2" domain="[('id','not in',field1)]" />
<field name="field3" domain="[('id','not in',field1),('id','not in',field2)]" />
<field name="field4" domain="[('id','not in',field1),('id','not in',field2),('id','not in',field3)]" />
```

You need to define more conditions as per your need.
like,

2nd field must not contain first field value.

3rd field must not contain first and second field value and so on.

[Click to refer Domain in odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#domains)

Comment: if i get more than 10 fields

Comment: in a single model you refer same model more than 10 times ?